# pymysql не изменяет значение

Tags: python, mysql, sql, pymysql

Я делаю бота для вк, есть функция добавления монетки на счет пользователя, но значение money не изменяется.

```
cur = con.cursor()

cur.execute("""CREATE TABLE users(id INT(15),
    money INT(255)
    )""")

def send_message(user_id, message, keyboard=None):
    session.method('messages.send',{
        "user_id": user_id,
        "message": message,
        "random_id": 0
    })

 
 
for event in VkLongPoll(session).listen():
    if event.type == VkEventType.MESSAGE_NEW and event.to_me:
        text = event.text.lower()
        user_id = event.user_id

        if text == 'добавить 1 монетку':
            cur.execute(f'UPDATE users SET money = {1} WHERE id = "{user_id}"')
            send_message(user_id, 'Монетка добавлена на ваш счет!')
```

Значение не изменяется, оно было на нуле и осталось. Как можно это исправить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы забыли:

```
con.commit()
```

`cur.execute` выполняется внутри транзакции. Автоматически (то есть без `con.commit`), транзакция аннулируется.

Ещё **очень советую вам почитать книжки про то, как использовать базы данных**. В вашем коде, например, присутствует очень распространенная среди начинающих ошибка, [**SQL Injection**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/775399/240613) называется, которая может потенциально дать возможность пользователю делать всё что он желает с вашей базой данных. Например всё стереть нафиг. Не думаю, что вы этого хотите.